# Is there a penalty in Uno for incorrectly accusing a player of failing to call "uno"?

Tags: uno

I was playing Uno with my family when I had two cards left in my hand. My sister yelled out "one card", thinking I have one card left and have failed to call "uno".

Does she now need to take two cards (which is the penalty for getting caught when failing to call "uno")?

Comment: Did you try looking in the [rules](https://www.unorules.com/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is beyond trivial, and a fundamental part of the game.

Comment: @Nij As far as I know down-voting is the way to go with questions that don't show any research effort. Although trivial, this question appears to be on-topic. And we don't have any policy for closing questions that can be answered by simply reading a rulebook. Not that I wouldn't be happy with one.

Comment: I'm okay with questions that can be answered by a rulebook when they require a modicum of interpretation or meta-knowledge or otherwise additional effort. But this is literally reading the text of the rule, monkey-see-monkey-do stuff. Stack Exchange is meant to be the place of enthusiasts and professionals, not a sentient replacement for Google. @tsuma534

Comment: The negative comments seem to be on the wrong track. The original question certainly needed some cleaning up, but in it's present form as far as I can tell it is actually a very *good* question about something which is *not* covered at all in the rules - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that yelling out "one card" is the way your group has decided to implement this [rule](https://www.unorules.com/):

> If [the player with one card is] caught not saying “Uno” by another player before any card has been played by other players, the player must draw two new cards.

That rule does not establish a penalty for *incorrectly* "catching" another player not saying Uno. You could add a house rule to this effect, especially if people abuse the rule by yelling "one card" incorrectly very often. However the house rule would itself be open to abuse since it would encourage people to mask how many cards they have, so I would only add it if people are being really annoying with the incorrect calls (and in that case why are you playing with really annoying people anyway?)